# Is there a way in Visual Studio to convert text to a C# string literal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macros

Is there a way in Visual Studio to convert text to a C# string literal and back?

For example if I have the text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
```

can I easily convert it to:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing\n" + 
"elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut\n" +
"laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat."
```

and then convert it back using a macro or some utility?

Comment: Python has '''sjdfhaskjfh''' string :)
Would you type it in first before applying a macro?
Intellisense will screw you up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are add ons for that
take a look here
http://arcanecode.com/2006/11/20/visual-studio-add-ins-paste-as/

Comment: Great. Smart paster does most of what I need. I can live without going the other direction for now.

Answer (score 7):

You know you can do

```
@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing  
elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut  
laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat."
```

right?  @-strings (a.k.a. "verbatim string literals") can contain newlines.

Comment: However, that won't help for quotes.

Comment: You're correct on that; those would have to be escaped with "".

Comment: Indeed, though highlighting the string and Ctrl-H find-and-replace-in-region of " to "" works pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2013, you can install 'SmartPaster2013' via Extensions and Updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefix the string with an @ you can get something similar:

```
string lorem = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.";
```

This will preserve the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress CodeRush can [do this](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2010/03/09/slicing-and-dicing-strings-with-coderush-for-visual-studio.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use:

```
string s = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing  
elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut  
laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 
";
```

Comment: Unless the string has quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind extra whitespace, you can enclose it in quotes and include the `@` symbol at the beginning which means 'literal.' Like this:

```
string s = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can load the value into a variable and copy **Value** from Locals Window by double-clicking so it's highlighted as text

It's a little fidgety to do, but can be done.

Or you write a long tedious function like this one

```
static string ToCodeString(string s)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        char c;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < s.Length)
        {
            c = (char)s[i];

            if (c == 34 || c == 92 || c == 93) //speechmarks backslash
            {
                sb.Append("\\" + c);
            }
            else if (c == 13)
            {
                sb.Append("\\r");
            }
            else if (c == 10)
            {
                sb.Append("\\n");
            }
            else if (c == 0)
            {
                sb.Append("\\0");
            }
            else if (c == 7)
            {
                sb.Append("\\a");
            }
            else if (c == 8)
            {
                sb.Append("\\b");
            }
            else if (c == 12)
            {
                sb.Append("\\f");
            }
            else if (c == 9)
            {
                sb.Append("\\t");
            }
            else if (c == 11)
            {
                sb.Append("\\v");
            }
            else if (c >= 32 && c <= 127) //ascii
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            //else <-- if you want to represent unicode in ascii
            //{
            //    sb.Append(string.Format(@"\u{0:x4}", (int)c));
            //}
            else
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            i++;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
}
```